# Get whole language file array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm newbie in **laravel 4.0**.

- How to get the whole array from `lang/en/texts.php`?
- Is there a `Lang::getAll()` method?

My goal is to generate keywords/description in my base controller, to fill them into the the meta tags and other places in the DOM in the master blade template. If my approach is completely wrong, please tell me!

Generating the keywords and description from an associative array is NOT the problem, but the lack of knowledge about the framework. And, I was googling for quite a time before ending up here...

Working with blade templates:
This is my BaseController:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';
    private $keyWords = array();

    private function getKeyWords () {
        // ???

    }

    public function getIndex() {
        return View::make('home')
            ->with('errorcanvas', trans('texts.canvas'))
            ->with('errortextwebgl', trans('texts.webgl'))
            ...;
    }

    ...

}
```

---

I found something in the [API](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Translation/FileLoader.html):

`Illuminate\Translation\FileLoader load()` which loads the messages with a given `locale`
...

Comment: see @Justin answer for the correct Laravel way of achieving this. It should be the accepted answer

Comment: @Gaz_Edge Yes you're right.

Comment: I needed this to include messages in javascript. thank you

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can [get the entire array](http://laravel.com/docs/localization) with `Lang::get()`.

```
$array = Lang::get('pagination'); // return entire array
$text  = Lang::get('pagination.next'); // return single item
```

Comment: Gotcha: If you have array keys in pagination.php called 'next.page' and 'next.item' it will not work with `Lang::get('pagination.next')`. You have to make sure that 'next' is an array. This took me a while to figure out :)

Comment: Info : Lang::get('messages') will fetch all the lang array under lang/messages folder in Laravel 5.4. May be of help to someone

Comment: what about en.json like language files? How could I fetch all content of the file? Except for file reading ;)

Comment: @aod to load the json files, I've found if you use `\Lang::get('*')` you will get it all as an array.

Answer (score 17):

Lets say, a language file: lang/en/countries.php

```
return [
 'afg' => 'Afghanistan',
 'ala' => 'Aland',
 'alb' => 'Albania',
 'dza' => 'Algeria',
 'asm' => 'American Samoa'
];
```

Retrieving lines from the language file with **Lang::get()** method

```
$array = Lang::get('countries'); // return entire array
$text  = Lang::get('countries.afg'); // return single item
```

for **Laravel 5.0** & above, You may also use the **trans** helper function, which is an alias for the **Lang::get()** method.

```
$array = trans('countries'); // return entire array
$text = trans('countries.afg'); // return single item
```

[Find out more on Laravel docs...](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/localization#basic-usage)

Answer (score 6):

Here's how yo can load them:

```
Route::get('test', function() 
{
    $a = File::getRequire(base_path().'/app/lang/en/pagination.php');

    foreach($a as $key => $value)
    {
        echo "$key => $value<br>";
    }
});
```

If you need to load them all, you can use [this](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/File.html#method_directories):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

$languages = File::directories(base_path().'/app/lang/');
```

I had to find a way to create an language import command in my Glottos package: https://github.com/antonioribeiro/glottos.

Comment: Thanks Antonio! i didn't find anything about the File Class in the API, What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 2):

Antonio answered loading of language file perfectly, but I don't like your approach.
It can be done much easier. Why not to do it this way?

```
// view file
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="description" content="{{ trans('texts.description') }}">
    ...
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

You do not need to send all the content thru controller, which makes your controller clean.

Comment: Sure for 1 line, but i need the whole array. See @Antonio's solution

Comment: Now I understand your approach. Also a nice one. The reason is that I'll be using it at other places in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

you can actually use the helper function `__('lang_file')` as well.