# How to use / retrieve Laravel translations in JS?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel translations like:

```
{{trans('general.myIdText')}}
```

or with

```
<?php __('general.myIdText'');?>
```

I have no idea on how to retrieve 'general' texts in JS

I tried like

```
var trans = JSON.parse(<?=trans();?>);
```

I can also see many properties with

```
<?php print_r(trans());?>
```

But this also contains many "protected properties"

Any way to do it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get whole language file array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718291/get-whole-language-file-array)

Comment: ^ Please check if this works. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65413882/laravel-get-the-content-of-a-translation-file-as-an-array

Comment: Does ``trans('general')`` work? It should return all the trans from the general file.